# Insecure <form> call - HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, https

> Insecure  call. Found on line # 1 in file:
>   www.mydomain.something/index.html is preventing the secure padlock

One site I have not use CloudFront so I changed the **base URL** to ..`https://mydomain.something` and that worked.

I have another site which uses CloudFront so the URLs are different each base URL is set using `www.randomlettershereruegherh.cloudfront.something` and not  `{{unsecure_base_url}}`

If I change the base URL by adding https will I have to change the other URLs as well for example from:

`http://randomlettershereruegherh.cloudfront.net/skin/`

to:

`https://randomlettershereruegherh.cloudfront.net/skin/`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got https working on a Magento 1.9 test site

```
Base url is set http
use secure frontend yes
```

and what made it work was this in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Another way is below which means the divert in Magento admin is not necessary

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

1.I am not using the divert to base in Magento 
2.Change all http to https in Magento admin
Use secure frontend
Use secure in admin

Answer (score 0):

Go to : `System > Configuration > Web > Secure` and make sure the following are set correctly :

- Base Link URL - `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL - `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL - `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base Javascript URL - `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

With this, the paths generated will follow `"Base URL"`.  If a page is secure everything on it will also be served secure.